# Policiy Gradient Infinite-Horizon Analysis

Tags: reinforcement-learning

Source: CS285 2023Fall homework2 analysis.
[image]

In the part B, the expectation $\mathbb{E}[R(\tau)] = \theta + \theta^2 ... = \theta/(1-\theta)$.
Derivate this with respect to $\theta$ is $1/(1-\theta)^2$.
But how to compute the gradient using policy gradients?(Part A)

[image]

I'm really confused for computing the expectation of the gradient of log of $\pi_\theta$(Trajectory).

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site! What's the source of your first picture? And the source of the second one?

Comment: Both pictures come from CS285 2023Fall homework2 analysis. I added this into question. : )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For part B, from this simple state diagram you're right we can directly compute the expected return without discounting as $\mathbb{E}_{\tau \sim \pi_{\theta}}R(\tau)=\theta(1-\theta)+2\theta^2(1-\theta)+3\theta^3(1-\theta)+...=\theta+\theta^2+\theta^3+...=\theta/(1-\theta)$, where $|\theta|<1$. Then take its gradient w.r.t $\theta$ we simply arrive at $1/(1-\theta)^2$.

For part A it seems supposed to use policy gradient theorem for a generic MDP to calculate the same, which is usually expressed as $\nabla_{\theta}J(\theta)=\mathbb{E}_{\tau \sim \pi_{\theta}}[\nabla_{\theta}\log\pi_{\theta}(\tau)R(\tau)]$ following your reference's notation with a random trajectory $\tau$. Similar to part B above to calculate the expected return, we can simplify the policy gradient as $$\nabla_{\theta}J(\theta)=\theta(1-\theta)·\nabla_{\theta}\log\theta(1-\theta)·1+\theta^2(1-\theta)·\nabla_{\theta}\log\theta^2(1-\theta)·2+...=\nabla_{\theta}\theta(1-\theta)·1+\nabla_{\theta}\theta^2(1-\theta)·2+...=\nabla_{\theta}(\theta(1-\theta)·1+\theta^2(1-\theta)·2+...)=\nabla_{\theta}(\theta/(1-\theta))$$, which obviously matches the result of the above Part B. Note here my answer didn't use or need the hint of your reference since only elementary convergent geometric series sum formula and basic calculus formula involving logarithm and division are actually involved.

Comment: Thanks for the answer which really helps a lot!

Comment: By MDP, do you mean Markov Decision Process? And, what does the letter J stand for?

Comment: @evaristegd J os the same as in your question, the loss

Comment: @Alberto , thanks. Do you know where did OP got those two pictures from? Is it a book?

Comment: @evaristegd section 8 https://rail.eecs.berkeley.edu/deeprlcourse/deeprlcourse/static/homeworks/hw2.pdf

Comment: @Alberto , thank you. How is it that you were able to find the source just by looking at the picture?

Comment: @evaristegd exact match on google, just search _"and verify that this matches the policy gradient"_ on google with quotes and you will find it

Comment: May I ask, how did you come up to the computation the expected return without discounting? Why did $\theta$ get higher exponents?

Comment: @Dave see the above question stated explicitly that *Do not use discounting* in bold font. Higher exponents for $\theta$ is just following multiplication rule of probability for the random trajectory $\tau$. Hope this clarifies and can get your upvote.

Comment: @cinch do you mean the joint probability formula?