# Computing variance of gradient of infinite horizon MDP

Tags: reinforcement-learning

This comes from CS285 2023Fall homework2.
I'm self-learning RL, but analysis question seems a little hard for me.

[image]
In question one, we could get
$\mathbb{E}_{\tau \sim \pi_{\theta}}R(\tau)=\theta(1-\theta)+2\theta^2(1-\theta)+3\theta^3(1-\theta)+...=\theta+\theta^2+\theta^3+...=\theta/(1-\theta)$, where $|\theta|<1$. Then take its gradient w.r.t $\theta$ we simply arrive at $1/(1-\theta)^2$.
\

But Question 2 is still confusing me.
The variance I compute as fllowed:
$$Variance = \sqrt{\sum_{t=1}^{\infty } ((t-1)\theta^{t-1}(1-\theta)\nabla_{\theta }\ln \theta^{t-1}(1-\theta ) - \frac{1}{(1-\theta)^2})^2}$$
But how to simplify it to eyeball the min/max?

Q3:I compute policy gradient use reward-to-go as followed, but I don't know why this is unbiased to $1/(1-\theta)^2$. And How to compute the variance...
$$
\nabla_{\theta}J_{\theta}=\sum_{T=1}^{\infty}\theta^{T-1}(1-\theta)\sum_{t=1}^{T-1}\nabla_{\theta}\ln\theta(T-t)
$$
$$
= \sum_{T=1}^{\infty}\theta^{T-1}(1-\theta)\frac{T^2 - T}{2\theta}
$$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Policiy Gradient Infinite-Horizon Analysis](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/45218/policiy-gradient-infinite-horizon-analysis)

Comment: The question was also queried by me. That question below only focus on the Q1 part and this question focus on Q2 and Q2.